# Charge nickel cadmium (NiCd) batteries with a nickel metal hydride (NiMH) Charger

Tags: electricity, batteries

I am using a portable wireless shaving machine. It was bundled with a nickel cadmium (NiCd) battery and a cradle + charger. The battery was 1.2v rechargeable one. I can operate the machine with a nickel metal hydride (NiMH) too. (It works same as NiCd)

Can I use the same machine with it cradle + charger to charge this NiMH battery?

Comment: Hm... the title and the question seems to be completely opposite.

Comment: I think that you are looking for: http://www.greenbatteries.com/nimh-battery-charger-faq/#NiCD%20charger%20for%20NiMH%20batteries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer NiMH cells are more resistant to overcharge, but older ones might be damaged if left too long on a NiCd charger. Though they have about the same endpoint voltage on charge, NiCd cells often have a catalyst to recombine the electrolyzed H2 and O2. Newer NiMH cells also have that catalyst and could be used with the NiCd charger, especially if not left on trickle charge indefinitely. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel%E2%80%93metal_hydride_battery